# Beginner Java project: how to delete an element from an array when it is one of the parameters?

Tags: java, arrays

Im working on a coin sorter project. At the moment I'm trying to create a method that takes two values (total value, and a type of coin), and will return the total value sorted out into all the coin denominations EXCEPT the type of coin.
For example multiCoinCalculator(562, 50) would return "2x200p, 1x100p, 0x50p, 3x20p, 0x10p with a remainder of 2p".

I have a pretty good idea of how to do this but I am struggling to remove a value the "type of coin" value from my array.

//multiCoinCalculator method

```
    public String multiCoinCalculator(int totalValExchange, int coinType) {
        int[] list= {10,20,50,100,200};
        list = ArrayUtils.removeElement(list, coinType);
        return list;
    }
```

Here you can see what I am trying to do so far. I am just wanting to remove the coin type (would be 50 with the example), from my list. I have been fiddling with it for ages but cant seem to get it to work at all!

The errors that come up are "ArrayUtils cannot be resolved" and "type mismatch: cannot convert from int[] to String"

Any ideas? Would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The first error is that the compiler doesn't know what ArrayUtils is. You have to tell it where it can find ArrayUtils. The second error is that you're returning an array, but in the return type of the method you say you will return a String.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an array here which is a fixed-size data structure where you can't remove an element from it, you need an array list here, try this,

```
       ArrayList<Integer> list new ArrayList<>();
       list.add(10);
       list.add(20);
       list.add(50);
       list.add(100);
       list.add(200);
       // then remove it by using an index
       list.remove(2); // this will remove 3rd element.
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should call the ArrayList as follows.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
List<Integer> coins= new ArrayList<>();
coins.add(10);
coins.add(20);
coins.add(50);
coins.add(100);
coins.add(200);
List<Integer> result = multiCoinCalculator(coins,520,50); }
```

You should pay attention to this when calling the method to keep the answer in an ArrayList.

```
List<Integer> result = multiCoinCalculator(coins,520,50);
```

Accordingly, you can define a function like this.

```
 public static List<Integer> multiCoinCalculator(List<Integer> c, int totalValExchange,int coinType) { 

        c.remove(coinType);} 

        /*In the meantime, I think the procedures to be done are the main point of this work, which is given as homework. */

        return List<Integer> result; // if you want keep result via using ArrayList return must be an ArrayList}
```

You can make your new calculations with the new list you will create.
You can take a look at **the Greedy Algorithm** to solve your problem.